# Execute a program by double-clicking the taskbar and/or the desktop, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, desktop, directoryopus

It would be so useful, and not very difficult, because in fact I have [Directory Opus](http://www.gpsoft.com.au/) installed (a very powerful windows explorer alternative) and it does exactly that, but only by double-clicking the desktop, not the taskbar.

Similar options with middle-click would also be nice, such as scrolling the taskbar (maybe cycling directly through the Alt-Tab window).

[7 Task Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) is close to this, actually, but it doesn't do what I would like.

Comment: I've been looking for this too, and I'm starting to think it's just not possible.

Answer (score 2):

An [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script can convert double-click on the taskbar to click. In fact, with AutoHotkey you can do anything you like with any mouse/keyboard event.

The article [Single click vs Double click on tray icon](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/33843-single-click-vs-double-click-on-tray-icon/) contains this script that
you can adapt to your needs, by ignoring the second click of the double-click:

```
#Persistent
Menu, Tray, Add, TEST, TEST
Menu, Tray,Default, TEST
Menu, Tray, Click, 1
Return

TEST:
If x = 5 ;here you can set how many clicks user can do max
    Return
x++
SetTimer, Run, 300 ;here you need to experiment to suit you
SetTimer, DEL, 350
Return

Run:
SetTimer, Run, Off
MsgBox % x
Return


DEL:
SetTimer, DEL, Off
x=
Return
```