# Email client Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, email-client

It seems that Opera is removing that integrated mail client (it doesn't exist in Opera 15) :(

I was thinking to switch to Chrome and wondering if Chrome has an extension or something that brings mail into the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you have gmail, I recommend using the Gmail interface but also be sure to find the right extensions. Offline mail has been mentioned, but look to [Checker Plus for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/checker-plus-for-gmail/oeopbcgkkoapgobdbedcemjljbihmemj) This extension will make your experience better as it polls your accounts every few seconds and provides live notifications saving you the trouble of even keeping a tab of mail open.

Comment: I would use that everyday when i was a chrome user, I tried them all, Checker plus is the best, rest are rubbish

Answer (score -1):

[Gmail Offline mail browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-offline/ejidjjhkpiempkbhmpbfngldlkglhimk?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) would fulfil this need, providing your using a Google Mail account.  As a side note there's a Firefox add-on which looks very similar to Opera's Mail, [Simple-Mail](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/simple-mail/) which supports POP3/IMAP.

Comment: Sorry for leaving a comment here, but there's no way to contact you on the other question since you didn't leave a comment. What exactly are you looking for here? http://superuser.com/questions/421245

Answer (score -1):

I vote for checker plus on chrome but you don't have to leave opera, pick one from [here](https://addons.opera.com/en/search/?query=gmail), I used to have [this](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/gmail-on-speed-dial/?display=en)